# Detect URLs and #tags in Django CharField and add style to it

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

For now on I have in my template a paragraph like this `<p class="...">{{ post.content }}</p>` and if this Post's content contains a link or #hashtag it is rendered as a normal text with the rest of the post. How can I customize it? For example change text-color and add  tag around it?

Comment: You can create your own function as tag filter to do so, and wrap `{{post.content|tagfilter_name}}` there is a bunch of way to id, for instance you can use python module `re` to style hashtags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in comment, you can use custom tag filter to wrap your content, and use **Regular Expression** to generate links and hashtags

Create your tags file, and name it as you want:

```
tag_filter_name.py
```

If you're not familiar with custom tag filter creation, you can learn more about it in the [Official Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)

```
from django import template
import re

register = template.Library()

def generate_link(link):
    return '<a class="link" href="{}">{}</a>'.format(link, link)

def generate_hashtag_link(tag):
    # Free to configuree the URL the way adapted your project
    url = "/tags/{}/".format(tag)
    return '<a class="hashtag" href="{}">#{}</a>'.format(url, tag)
```

And then, you create the function what will be used as tag filter

```
@register.filter
def render_content(obj):
    text = re.sub(r"#(\w+)", lambda m: generate_hashtag_link(m.group(1)),obj)
    return re.sub(r"(?P<url>https?://[^\s]+)", lambda m: generate_link(m.group(1)),text)
```

If you want Django to mark it as safe content, you can do the following:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe # import function

    ''' function codes here '''
    return mark_safe(re.sub(r"(?Phttps?://[^\s]+)", 
             lambda m: generate_link(m.group(1)),text))
```

And finally, to use it in your template, don't forget to load it

```
{% load tag_filter_name %}

{{ post.content|render_content }}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 0):

Best way: custom tag filters here is the docs URL
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/

Good way: If you know JS create a function that handles the formatting on the front end

in HTML:
    onload="myfunction("{{post.content}}")"

in JS sort for the string containing the # wrap it in a span or other element and style away. then replace the inner HTML with your new formatted piece. This will save rendering time on the server and also frees you up from having to loop thru the list of posts in the view

Ok way: not preferred but if you hate js and only want to work in python (understandable). You need to loop through the list of posts separate out the items of the post format them the way you like with inline style. then add them to a new object that you will append to the end of a new list of posts that you will then pass thru to context. This is a real pain please don't do this if you can help it at all.

the tag filters are awsome take advantage but if they won't work for your use case I would highly advise using vanilla JS